# How to clean up all windows of tmux?

Tags: tmux, window

[image]

When I pressed Ctrl+b w, I saw the windows I used before. How could I delete all of them?

Comment: It would have been better if you had requested a migration of [your SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683763/how-to-clear-up-all-windows-in-tmux) here... Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tmux man page:

```
  kill-window [-a] [-t target-window]
               (alias: killw)

         Kill the current window or the window at target-window, removing it 
         from any sessions to which it is linked.  The -a option kills all 
         but the window given with -t.
```

So, at your command prompt try:

```
$ tmux kill-window -a
```

If you have one window that you want to preserve include it as well:

```
$ tmux kill-window -a -t:<window number>
```

Comment: Thanks... 
Actually, I tried `man tmux` and found the `kill-widow` command. However, maybe I did a typo, It did work at that time.
This time it succeeds.